# How to make a code keep repeat with delay when a button is pressed and holded?

Tags: javascript, html, button, setinterval, replit

I want to make a code be runned when a button is pressed and holded with a time delay(repeat)

Here is the code i used:

```
var holdup;
function hold() {
  holdup = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1) 
  }, 100);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(holdup)
}
```

```
<div class="up">
     <input id="up" type="button" value="Up" onmousedown="hold()" onmouseup="stop()">
</div>
```

I think I made some mistake in the setInterval or onmousedown part because I've tried to change to code to be:

```
var holdup;
function hold() {
    console.log(2)
  holdup = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1) 
  }, 100);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(holdup)
}
```

and it will only have the "2" in console log when the button is clicked(not hold)

Comment: It works fine for me. What result do you expect to see?

Comment: i expect to see the 1 will be keep sending in console log but it wont send any message when i hold the button

Comment: It sends `1` every 100 ms. Do you want it to be logged without any intervals?

Comment: i mean idk why it wont send `1` in console log

Comment: maybe is the phone problem?

Comment: Are you on phone?

Comment: i now use `document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("touchstart", hold(up))
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("touchend", stop(up))

var holdup;
function hold() {
  holdup = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1)
  }, 100);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(holdup)
}` but after i added the "touchend", the code don't work, how to fix it?

Comment: What is `up`? It's not defined

Comment: oh is `document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("touchstart", hold())
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("touchend", stop())

var holdup;
function hold() {
  holdup = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1)
  }, 100);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(holdup)
}`

Comment: oh nvm i used ontouchstart and ontouchend instead